# Twitter Bootstrap "Dropdown Toggle" on "btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary"?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to add "Dropdown Toggle" on "btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" button ?

I have link "btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" like this

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Download</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ky34/2/

I am trying to add "Dropdown Toggle" to above link by adding "btn-block btn-lg " in the class of button, and adding "btn-lg " in the dropdown class like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Download</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ky34/3/

But it's not displaying on the same line, how can i fix this?

The dropdown is coming on the next line.

Comment: it is because of the `btn-block` class remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because of the `btn-block` class remove it, it sets `display: block`

```
<div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7DPAz/)

Comment: so how can make it longer like this http://jsfiddle.net/9ky34/2/ which gets stretched to arent divs width. which is 285px. thanks

Comment: okie, got it , i just added style="width:285px;" on the button, thanks.

Comment: @AMB that is a bad idea since if responsiveness is enabled it will fail

Comment: This one looks nice but the height is not same as btn-lg btn-primary. i tried adding height:100% , but it doesnt work.

Comment: idk if its bug or something else, r is it just me , but when i hover the dropdown links , the anchor text cant be readable, here is what i did in my final code. http://jsfiddle.net/7DPAz/3/

Comment: indeed, theme css is causing this.

Comment: its been fixed in bootstrap 3.0.3